# pass javascript message to csharp

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript code that works wonderfully:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maxWords = 100;
    function limitLengthInWords(field)
    {
        var value = field.value,
            wordCount = value.split(/\S+/).length - 1,
            re = new RegExp("^\\s*\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){0," + (maxWords - 1) + "}");
        if (wordCount >= maxWords)
        {
            field.value = value.match(re);
            alert("Max reached");
        }
        document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = maxWords - wordCount;
    }
</script>
```

how do i replaced the alert("Max reached") so that it shows the validation message for the textarea that i am checking:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description)
```

can i do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maxWords = 100;
    function limitLengthInWords(field)
    {
        var value = field.value,
            wordCount = value.split(/\S+/).length - 1,
            re = new RegExp("^\\s*\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){0," + (maxWords - 1) + "}");
        if (wordCount >= maxWords)
        {
            field.value = value.match(re);
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(field,"Max reached");
        }
        document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = maxWords - wordCount;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are trying to implement an extra layer of validation on top of JQuery val and the ASP.NET MVC validation ?

Comment: yes. i am trying to impose a word count limit in textarea. thanks.

Comment: any reason you don't want to write a custom validator for that ?

Comment: I can write a custom validator, how do i do that, sorry i am a newbie to this whole c# mvc

Comment: Here, try this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613330/Building-Client-JavaScript-Custom-Validation-in-AS), it should do the trick. It's quite complicated of course, but a much better approach to the problem at hand

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have a some hidden text that you show.

```
<span style="display:none;" class="max-reached">Max Reached</span>

$(".max-reached").show()
```

Alternatively try using a library that does this and includes a countdown. Such as [NobleCount](http://tpgblog.com/noblecount/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your model annotated correctly, i am using password property as an example

```
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Error Message")]
public string Password
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Change this  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(field,"Max reached"); 
to I am assuming $(field) is the id such as $('#Password') all you have to do is access the data information stored by mvc $(field).data('val-length')